# how to move a "li" tag into another "ul" tag without removing the first "li"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

how to move a "li" tag into another "UL" tag without removing the first "li"?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#id").click(function () {
            $("#id li").last().replace('#id li');
        });
    });
```

also I use this code but didn't work.

Comment: Hi parsa and welcome to SO. Your question is very bare bones. Consider adding more details about what the result should be and what exactly isn't working. Also be sure to include your HTML and make a [stacksnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in which we can run your code. Read [how to create a Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidelines on your snippet.

Comment: Most jquery methods move an existing element - so use [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to create a copy (or use `.html()`)

Comment: clone() maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquerys [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents) method to "copy" the element

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#id").click(function () {
            $("#id li").last().clone().appendTo('.anotherElement')
        });
    });
```